# How Do You Explain This Object Literal?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I am new to Javascript Object Literal, and I have problem understanding the mechanism behind this logic, and because of that, I don't know the right keyword to search either in Google, or SO.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
var dialog = {
    open: function(x){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
    },
    type: {
        settings: {
            controller: '',
            click: false,
            clas: ''
        },
        foo: function(){
            this.settings.controller = 'Foo controller'
            this.settings.clas = 'Foo class'
            dialog.open(this.settings)
        },
        bar: function(){
            this.settings.click = true
            dialog.open(this.settings)
        }
     }
}
```

This is my issue:

```
//A
dialog.type.foo();
//B
dialog.type.bar();
//C
dialog.type.foo();
```

Why is it that when I run `//C`, `dialog.type.settings` is still retaining the value from `foo`?
How can I default back to `dialog.type.settings`?

Comment: In what context are you running the code?  `this` probably is pointing to the global object.

Comment: @DavinTryon well not if the functions are called as described.

Comment: This is the only context. You can run the code and test it. Or maybe I'll provide the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one object to work with, so anything you changed in previous steps are "carried along" until you explicitly change them.

To work with a new dialog object each time I would recommend using a function that returns a new instance each time and hide the `settings` and `open` properties:

```
function dialog()
{
    var settings = {
        controller: '',
        click: false,
        clas: ''
    },
    open = function(x) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    };

    return {
        type: {
            foo: function() {
                settings.controller = 'Foo controller';
                settings.clas = 'Foo class';
                open(settings);
            },
            bar: function() {
                settings.click = true;
                open(settings);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And then:

```
var a = dialog();
a.type.foo();

var b = dialog();
b.type.bar();

var c = dialog();
c.type.foo();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yeciguke/2/edit?js,console,output)

It avoids the issues you would otherwise face with using `this` in all kinds of contexts, because `settings` and `open` are always within the scope of the API that you return from the `dialog()` function.

Comment: `'dialog.open' is not a function`. Apparently I can't access `dialog` internally.

Comment: `this` is not the scope you're looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you. You have widen my insight on this. However, this `dialog()` can also be instantiated by the `new` keyword, right? What's the difference, in layman's term?

Comment: @rolodex Yeah it can be instantiated with both `dialog()` and `new dialog()` ... there's not much of a difference other than typing, the resulting object from `new dialog()` isn't strictly a `dialog` instance ... i.e. `instanceof` check will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your "foo" function is explicitly and deliberately changing the values of those "settings" properties. There's just one "settings" object, after all. If you want to revert the values, you'll have to write a function to do that.

Comment: …or clone the object before modifying it.

Comment: How do I clone the object please?

Comment: @rolodex see the answer from Jack; it's got all you need I think.